# Automate Develop persona in Affinity Photo 1.7?

Tags: raw, automation, affinity-photo

I am processing a bunch of RAW images in Affinity Photo v1.7 (on OS X), and for each photo I want to perform the same adjustments.  I have looked in all the usual places for repeating my steps but so far have not found any way to automate duplication of my work flow.  (For example the Macro recorder is not available in the Development persona).

Is this possible in Affinity? Or do I have to brush up my OS X Automator skills?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [discussions in Affinity forum](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/54840-how-to-copy-a-set-of-adjustments-in-the-develop-persona/) you can't directly copy/paste the development settings from one photo to another. What is offered is to create preset from the first photo and then apply this preset to the rest of them.

And ([from this tread](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/24693-is-there-a-way-to-copy-settings-from-one-photo-to-the-next/)) you can record macros and run it on the rest of photos. Or use LUTs

You can also try to copy/paste the adjustment layers (from one photo to others)

Comment: I'm trying to replicate changes in the Develop persona, so there are no layers to copy paste and no access to the macro recording - they are only available when you are in the Photo persona.  The same with the LUT approach, its only a Persona feature